# Bootstrap 4 Menu and Logo won't align

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure this out but can't find the reason why.

[image]

The menu and the logo won't align to each other.

Here's my Nav HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">

                        <!-- Toggle Button -->
                        <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
                            ☰
                        </button>

                        <!-- Nav Content -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="nav-content">
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="">MIGRATE</a>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                                <li class="nav-item active">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#home">Home</a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#grid">Grid System</a>
                                </li>


                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#tooltips">Tooltips</a>
                                </li>


                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#tables">Tables</a>
                                </li>



                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#carousel">Carousel</a>
                                </li>


                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#cards">Cards</a>
                                </li>


                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link scrollto" href="#forms">Forms</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </nav>
```

As you can see the brand and the menu doesn't look good as its not floating next to each other.

You can check the JSFIDDLE HERE: https://jsfiddle.net/683onLeg/

Comment: remove this style ul{ margin-top: 40px;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this style, it'll align it and will put it exactly middle of menu bar

```
ul.navbar-nav{
    margin-top: 0;
}
ul.navbar-nav li a{
    line-height: 24px !important;
}
```

[See the attached image for refrence of your header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4Tlk.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have a global class on ul's that adds a 40px margin to the top of any ul.  If you remove or override that rule, everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there is a blanket style as follows:

```
ul {
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Either remove that style, which could mess up the way other`<ul>`'s display in your layout, or override the margin only for the `ul.navbar-nav` class by specifying it:

```
ul.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```